# Can't $subtract a timestamp from a timestamp in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

When I run the following query the `cant $subtract atimestamp from a timestamp` occurred. Is there any alternative way to subtract two timestamp or convert the timestamp to integer and then do the subtract?

```
    {
        "collection": "visits_logs",
        "aggregate": [
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": {
                        "_sid": "$_sid"
                    },
                    "first1": {
                        "$first": "$_time"
                    },
                    "last1": {
                        "$last": "$_time"
                    },
                    "HTTP_REFERER_HOST": {
                        "$first": "$HTTP_REFERER_HOST"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "length": {
                        "$subtract": ["$last1","$first1"]
                    },
                    "HTTP_REFERER_HOST": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$HTTP_REFERER_HOST",
                    "length": {
                        "$avg": "$length"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

The complete error is:

Error:

```
Assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "cant $subtract atimestamp from a timestamp",
    "code" : 16556,
    "codeName" : "Location16556"
} : aggregate failed

_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:370:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1319:5
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: Can you complete your question with some sample documents from the collection?